# Parse Greasemonkey metadata and/or grab comments from within a function

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

```
function blah(_x)
{
  console.info(_x.toSource().match(/\/\/\s*@version\s+(.*)\s*\n/i)); 
}

function foobar()
{
  // ==UserScript==
  // @version    1.2.3.4
  // ==/UserScript==

  blah(arguments.callee);
}

foobar();
```

Is there any way to do this using JavaScript? I want to detect the version number / other attributes in a Greasemonkey script but as I understand it, `.toSource()` and `.toString()` strip out comments<sup>1</sup>.

I don't want to wrap the header block in `<><![CDATA[ ]><>` if I can avoid it, and I want to avoid having to duplicate the header block outside of the comments if possible.

Is this possible? Are there alternatives to `toSource()` / `.toString()` that would make this possible?

[1] - http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=3231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no really good way for a Greasemonkey script to know its own metadata (or comments either).   That is why every "autoupdate" script ([like this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/45904)) requires you to set extra variables so that the script will know its current version.

As aularon said, the only way to get the comments from a JS function is to parse the source HTML of the `<script>` tag or of the file.

However, **there is a trick** that might work for you.  You can **read in your own GM script as a resource** and then parse that source.

For example:

1. Suppose your script was named `MyTotallyKickassScript.user.js`.
2. Now add a `resource` directive to your script's [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) like so:
   `// @resource        MeMyself MyTotallyKickassScript.user.js`
   Notice that there is no path information to the file, GM will use a relative path to copy the resource, one time, when the script is **first** installed.
3. Then you can access the script's code using [`GM_getResourceText()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceText), like so:

   ```
   var ThisFileSource = GM_getResourceText ("MeMyself");  
   //Optional for Firebug users: console.log (ThisFileSource);
   ```
4. You can parse `ThisFileSource` to get the comments you want.
5. [A script that parses Greasemonkey metadata from a source file is here](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Knowing_Your_Own_Metadata).  You should be able to adapt it with little effort.

Comment: That is actually a pretty damn awesome trick - one of those "why didn't I think of that" kind of things =]

Comment: Just a quick note for anybody else reading, scripts uploaded to userscripts.org get renamed to their {scriptID}.user.js resulting in an error on install if you don't predict the filename correctly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript engine will ignore comments, the only way to do that is to string process `<script>`'s `innerHTML`, or string process an `AJAX` request that fetches the `.js` file, if it was an external file.

Comment: This is for within a Greasemonkey script which makes it not possible (to my knowledge) to do this as you suggest