# Get script's own source from Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, reflection, greasemonkey, self-reference

I know that with basic JS you can read a `<script>`'s source code like so:

```html
<pre id="scriptContents"></pre>
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript">
  var script = document.getElementById('myScript');
  var contents = script.innerHTML;
  scriptContents.innerText = contents;
</script>
```

So my question is: **Is there any way similar to this in Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey?** I want to be able to read the Greasmonkey script's source code as string.

The reason I'm asking is because the Greasemonkey script is magically included to the page and doesn't have a "physical" representation like the above `<script>` block.

*More background*: I'm writing a script but it needs a lot of styles and also a Mustache template which is really hard to provide in JavaScript **in a readable form**. I want to prevent having the escape every single apostrophe or quote character and also joining the string or adding `\` at the end of the line. I found a tricky way to do this, but still looking for alternatives. Here's the current version:

```
function hereDoc(f) { return f.toString().replace(/^[^\/]*\/\*!/, '').replace(/\*\/[^\/]*$/, ''); }
$('head').append(hereDoc(function() {/*!
    <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        <div>...
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        lots.of #css { code: here; }
    </style>
*/}));
```

Comment: I am curious. Why would you need this? You have the code right in front of you. Why would you need to grab it again?

Comment: I want to have it in a variable, I know I (as a person) can read it, but I want it to be self-aware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Greasemonkey metadata and/or grab comments from within a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636076/parse-greasemonkey-metadata-and-or-grab-comments-from-within-a-function)